# Auto Padding Bottom?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to somehow fit the loader I'm showing you guys in the container. The problem is that if I do `padding-bottom`, the loader is just going to override the browser and its going to be displayed as an un-resized loader (which does not look professional at all).

Would love to know if anyone has any cool methods to be able to arrange this problem. (You can find my code at the bottom).

[image: This is what I want to do.]

This is my CSS so far:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 250px 50px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 20px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 25px;
  bottom: 10px;
`;
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: whats the issue? the space at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. P.D: glad to see you again!

Comment: so you want the container to always fill the whole screen essentially? Haha hey again :)

Comment: Just to fill it, but keep its margins. You know, look at the separation of the top, keep that on the bottom too, but always feel that space when the browser gets refreshed

Comment: so `position: absolute; bottom: 25px; left: 25px; right: 25px; top: 25px;`? or if you're using flex then just `flex: 1` and on the parent component make sure its full screen size

Comment: That worked! Add the answer so that I can validate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the container to [**fill the parent size minus the 25px of margin**](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-h99j6) you are specifying.

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 250px 50px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 20px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 25px;
`;
```

or if [**you are using flex you could do**](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-wfzqv)

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 250px 50px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 20px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 8px;
`;
```